# Passing Form data to Controller

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

So in my Javascript I am using form serialize the output is correct

> (issubmit=1&username=tester&password=test&cpassword=test&firstname=sdfds&lastname=fsdfdsf&gender=&email=pie%40aol.com&phone=&address=&phone=&address=)

When I try to pass it to my controller, I get nothing, `result = ""`. What am I doing wrong?

**Jquery:**

```
var dataString = $("form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/welcome/submit_form/',
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataString,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
        $('#ajax-content-container').html(data);
    }
});
```

**Controller:**

```
function submit_form() {
    $data = $this->input->post('dataString');
    echo "<p>result= ".$data."</p>";
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming it's `class welcome extends CI_Controller {}` and that `submit_form()` is a child of that class, and that you're extending the parent class within the construct functin?

Comment: that is correct ohgodwhy

Comment: to get serialize data you may use 
$formData = $this->input->post(); so There is no need to take data in array form from HTML page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller seems to be checking for a post parameter named 'dataString'. But this parameter doesn't seem to be being sent in your ajax request. When you serialize your form, it's combining all form fields into one url-encoded string. There's no reference to a 'dataString' parameter in here.

What you might want to do in your form is wrap every input field's name attribute like this:

```
<input type="text" name="dataString[username]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="dataString[password]" value="" />
```

After doing this, I believe you should be able to check for a parameter called "dataString" in your controller. It should be an array containing all the fields in key/value format. E.g.

```
function submit_form() {
    $data = $this->input->post('dataString');
    echo var_dump($data);
}
```

Comment: you are absolutely correct. I have an additional question if you have time, should i be formatting that array ( remove special chars, etc ) in the controller or in the model before I insert it into my DB?

Comment: You should really be asking this as a new question on Stackoverflow, as this can be a complicated question and that's what Stackoverflow is for.
This is a crucial topic you must understand before you run off coding something. I would not put it in the model, as validating a form's input is a process that will be common amongst all your entities in your project, not just for your users.
You should create a process for validating form data that can applied to any form across your project.